# need to read (echo) json by php

Tags: php, json, echo

i need to get json code that changed remotely and display the data in php
when user load the page. (echo it)

i have this code:
(JSON output:)

```
{
   "area 267":[
      "city1",
      "city2",
      "city3",
      "city4",
      "city5",
      "city6",
      "city7",
      "city8",
      "city9",
      "city10",
      "city11",
      "city12",
      "city13"
   ],
   "area 268":[
      "city14",
      "city15",
      "city16"
   ],
   "Coords":[
      "31.856128;34.760947",
      "31.8166376;34.729755",
      "31.857223;34.727432",
      "31.843444;34.751793",
      "31.831039;34.722577",
      "31.831504;34.756643",
      "31.817725;34.7223",
      "31.815936;34.752588",
      "31.819054;34.739162",
      "31.824913;34.747459",
      ";",
      "31.813987;34.719103",
      "31.833778;34.74009",
      "31.815936;34.752589",
      "31.819054;34.739163",
      "31.824913;34.747458",
   ],
   "ID":"1405796061262"
}
```

the coords lines is the sum of the all cities.

i need to echo the json like this:
(PHP output need to be like:)

```
ID: 1405796061262.
Areas: area267, area268.

Citys of Area267: city1, city2, ... city13. (echo all cities in the area)
Citys of Area268: city14, city15, city16. (echo all cities in the area)
```

i cant know the areas and the cities (that in the JSON file).

Thanks for helping :)

**EDIT: WORKING CODE**

```
<?php

$json_data = '{
   "area 267":[
      "city1",
      "city2",
      "city3",
      "city4",
      "city5",
      "city6",
      "city7",
      "city8",
      "city9",
      "city10",
      "city11",
      "city12",
      "city13"
   ],
   "area 268":[
      "city14",
      "city15",
      "city16"
   ],
   "ID":"1405796061262"
}';

$data = json_decode($json_data);
//var_dump($data);
echo 'ID: ';
echo $data->ID;
echo '.<br>';
echo 'Areas: ';

$areas = array();
foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
if (strpos($k, 'ID') !== 0 && strpos($k, 'Coords') !== 0) {
      $areas[] = $k;
}
}

echo implode(', ',$areas).'.<br /><br />';


foreach ($areas as $k => $v) {
      echo "Cities of ".$v.': ';
      $cities = array();
      $cities = null;
      foreach ($data->$v as $area) {
            $cities[] = $area;
      }
      echo implode(', ',$cities).'.<br />';
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't see your problem. First, you print the id and the areas, then you simply loop over all area and, for every area, loop over the cities (nested loop). Have you tried anything so far? Can you post some code that you wrote to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

first you can use `json_decode` to convert the json output into php object then you can easily loop it and get the exact field value.

here is the documentation link:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: i know the option of 'json_decode', but i dont know how to echo it like how i need. can you show me? thanks

Comment: did you check the documentation or otherwise you can use like this,

$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this should work

```
$data = json_decode($json_data);

echo 'ID '.$data['ID']."<br />";
echo 'Areas: ';

$areas = array();

foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
  if (strpos($k, 'area ') === 0) {
      $areas[] = $k;
  }
}

echo implode(',',$areas).'.<br /><br />';

foreach ($areas as $area) {
   echo "Cities of ".strtoupper($area).':';
   $cities = array();
   foreach ($data[$area] as $city) {
      $cities[] = $city;
   }
   echo implode(','.$cities).'.<br />';
}
```